# Javascript wait for Promises to return data then assign onClick event listener to perform action on returned data

Tags: javascript, promise, onclick, fetch, es6-promise

**(UPDATE: I'm now able to solve the issue with plotting the data by using async / await to wait for the promise to resolve... However, now I'm facing the issue with how to stop the `setInterval` timer that's in a closure.)**

#### I want to accomplish the following:

- <s>Send 10 fetch requests *sequentially* and measure response time for each request (in millisec)</s>
- <s>For each request push response time to an array</s>
- On click of a *start* button - starts the plotting of points with a predefined function: `drawChart(data)` . The points should be added every second.
- On click of a *stop* button - stop the plotting.

#### onLoad event listener:

```
window.onload = async function () {
   drawChart([]);
   const data = await fetchData(15);
   document.getElementById("start").onclick = () => plotData(data);

   // I want to be able to clearInterval on click of Stop button... but its not working...
   document.getElementById("stop").onclick = clearInterval(plotData);  
};
```

#### plot / fetch function:

```
const plotData = (data) => {
  let i = 0;
  // How do i clear this interval outside of this function?
  const interval = setInterval( () => {
    i++;
    if (i === data.length) { clearInterval(interval); }
    let newData = data.slice(0,i);
    drawChart(newData); 
    console.log('draw');
  }, 1000);
}

const fetchData = async (times) => {
  let url = `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-1295/lounging-dog.jpg`;
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    await fetch(url)
      .then( res => {
        end = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log('times', i+1);
        console.log('response milisec', end - start);            
        data.push({ xVal: i+1, yVal: end-start}); 
      })
      .catch( e => console.log(e));   
  }
  return data;
};
```

What I can't wrap my mind about is how to clearInterval in the window context when the setInterval is defined within a callback.

You can also see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alchuang/pen/wvwXrER) for more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for a promise to resolve use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
// get fetch call data
const data = await fetchData(10).then( (res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

// assign button onClick handler, data undefined
document.getElementById("start").onclick = drawChart(data);
```

A better way to do this is, instead of waiting for each promise in `fetchData` to resolve before starting the next fetch, is to create each promise and then await all of them. It would look something like this:

```js
const fetchData = async (times) => {
  const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    promises.push( 
      fetch(url)
      .then( res => {
        end = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log('times', i+1);
        console.log('response milisec', end - start);            
        return { xVal: i+1, yVal: end-start};
      })
      .catch( e => console.log(e))
     );
  }
  
  let data = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(data)

  return data;
};

fetchData(3);
```

Comment: Yes, the window.onload function would have to be made async

Comment: Amazing! This works, thanks! Now I'm facing my next problem: To plot the data per second basis and to stop it with a button -- I created a function with setInterval. However, there's also a requirement to use a stop button to stop the interval... how can i do so when the interval is in a closure?